# User friendly method to input HTML email from appscript

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a sheets where my team (with zero knowledge on Google Apps Script and HTML) fills with Customer Names and Customer Email Addresses and click on a button to execute my script.

I made a script where I retrieve those names and emails and send them a HTML-formatted email, all through App Script.

However, the email body keeps changing and 1) I don't have the time to keep change it on the HMTL page inside Apps scrip; and 2) My team don't know how to change it.

I imagine there's an easier way for them to input the email body they want, and then my function retrieves it and use it in the email.
One extra problem: on my script, I call variables to use on the html (like Customer Name).

Any thoughts?

(sorry for the long question)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+sheet+update+html+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way is to allow a range or many ranges in a sheet and use it, for instance

```
function sendEmail() {
  MailApp.sendEmail({to: 'the emails',
  subject: 'the subject', 
  htmlBody: myText()})
};
function myText(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('mySheet')
  var plage = sh.getRange('A1:H33'); 
  return (tableHTML(plage))
}
function tableHTML(plage){
  var data=plage.getDisplayValues()
  var taille=plage.getFontSizes()
  var fond=plage.getBackgrounds()
  var couleur=plage.getFontColors()
  var police=plage.getFontFamilies()
  var htmltable = '<table>';
  for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){
    htmltable += '<tr>';
    for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
      if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + '&nbsp;' + '</td>';} 
      else
        htmltable += '<td style="font-family:' + police[row][col] + '; background-color:' + fond[row][col] + '; color:' + couleur[row][col] + '; font-size:' + taille[row][col] + 'px;">' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
      }
      htmltable += '</tr>';
    }
  htmltable += '</table>';
  return htmltable
}
```

This solution preserve also the colors you use within your sheet.

Comment: thanks Mike, i'll try it out